# Add python project into a docker and test it in jupyter notebook

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am new to docker. I want to create a docker image that from tensorflow. 
    FROM tensorflow/tensorflow
I want to have a docker image such that when I run it, it opens jupyter notebook and also has my code in the folder. Right now I can run the image to have a jupyter notebook with tensorflow. But I couldn't figure out how to get my python code into the folder in jupyter notebook.

Comment: Please post the Dockerfile you have now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easy, you only have to create a Dockerfile, with the base image tensorflow/tensorflow, copy your current folder with the Jupyter notebooks in it to `/notebooks` and add an entrypoint which executes jupyterhub for you at startup:

```
FROM tensorflow/tensorflow
COPY . /notebooks/my-notebooks
ENTRYPOINT ["/run_jupyter.sh", "--allow-root"]
```

Build with

```
docker build -t my-tf .
```

And run it!

```
docker run -it -p 8888:8888 my-tf
```

To access jupyterhub use http://127.0.0.1:8888

Comment: Thanks! Very straight forward explanation. I think it is the basic of docker. Haha, lots of things need to learn.